# Saving time series data in MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using Node.js, MongoDB and mongoose and I am trying to store real time data.
I want to store data with DIFFERENT intervals. For example from 0.1 Hz to 30 Hz.
The idea is to have a 2D Array with minutes and seconds, and every element is an array again that can store as many values as it wants. (30 for 30 Hz)
Using [this](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb) approach my mongoose scheme looks the following:

```
var someTestSchema = new Schema({
  dataType: Number, // some Identifier
  data: [
    {
      minute: Number,
      values: [
        {
          second: Number,
          values: [
            {
              timestamp: Date,
              value: String,
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
  ],
```

First of all, I am not really sure if I did the Schema right and how to model the array indexes.

Second, how do I store this data using mongoose now?

Do I have to hardcode the "minutes" and "seconds" array?

Thanks for any help!